System.ArgumentException: Options.ClientId must be provided (Parameter 'ClientId')
I am trying to host my .NET core project (nopCommerce 4.7) on Windows server IIS, have published the files there but having an error:
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer

EventId: 2

SpanId: 15ef495fc1e97c42

TraceId: 9f6ade836602c22e139ae05a6b6f46d8

ParentId: 0000000000000000

RequestId: 80000192-0000-b300-b63f-84710c7967bb

RequestPath: /

Connection ID "12898309334399713681", Request ID "80000192-0000-b300-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Exception:

System.ArgumentException: Options.ClientId must be provided (Parameter 'ClientId') 

at  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions.Validate()    
at  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.Validate(String scheme)    
at  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddSchemeHelper>b__1(TOptions o)    
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ValidateOptions`1.Validate(String name, TOptions options)    
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)    
at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)    
at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)    
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache1.GetOrAdd[TArg](String name, Func3 createOptions, TArg factoryArgument)    
at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
at  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)    
at  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)    
at  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()


Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and TRY to format your code correctly!

This question is similar to: ASP.NET Core 2.0 - ArgumentException: Options.ClientId must be provided. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

When you host your website on IIS, Please delete
MultiFactorAuth.GoogleAuthenticator  and  ExternalAuth.Facebook  if it doesn't in use.
